# How to fix memory error caused by ujson.loads

Tags: python, ujson

I am trying to load a 2GB json file using ujson.loads, and getting a memory error:

```
  File "dict.py", line 70, in <module>
    dct = load_dict_file()
  File "dict_load.py", line 25, in load_latest_dict
    dct = ujson.loads(dict_txt)
MemoryError
```

I'm running my code on an EC2 machine (Linux) with enough free memory, using Python 3.7:

```
[ec2-user@ip]$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15463         269       14330          11         863       14911
Swap:             0           0           0
```

the code runs as expected on my local machine (windows), so not sure what seems to cause the memory error.
I considered using ijson, but it looks like it doesn't suit my use case (pasring the json file to load it key-by-key to rows in a table, using sqlalchemy session).

Thanks

Comment: Try a streaming parser, like this one (not personal a recommendation, just the first Google hit): https://pypi.org/project/json-stream-parser/

Comment: Please run `python --help` to see if you have [32 bit or 64 bit Python](https://www.pythonpool.com/python-memory-error#ezoic-pub-ad-placeholder-111) ?

Comment: I have a 64 bit Python

Comment: Look through the different solutions under the link i provided; if none of these help, IDK what could help !

Comment: thanks! I tried most of it, checking to see what else I can do.